# JWT refresh token or not

Tags: node.js, refresh, jwt

I was about to change my authentication strategy from straight jwt in httponly that expires once a day to a refresh / bearer token approach. However, since refresh tokens can create new tokens, isn't this introducing a huge risk? Why do people recommend this? Am I missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only thing you need to get a fresh is an old token then it useless because anyone who intercepts the token can just refresh it regularly and basically have perpetual access - just like a never expiring token.

If refreshing a token doesn't require user/pass and invalidates the old token then it is dangerous because someone who intercepts the token can make a new token for himself while invalidating the token for the real user at the same time. So not only someone would get access to your account - you would also loose access yourself, to add insult to the injury.

If the old tokens are still valid after getting new ones and no user/pass is needed then someone who intercepts the token can create thousands of new tokens and all of them would be valid, and all of them could be refreshed to get even more tokens. If they are stored in a database then it can be a vector for a denial of service attack. If they are not stored in the database then you have no way of knowing which one of those are still in circulation and there is no way of invalidating them.

If you need to use user/pass or some other credential to get a fresh token then it means that leaked token is only valid for some time because it cannot be refreshed using the token alone, but it also means that real users need to send their user/pass more often which means more possibilities for intercepting the credentials.

I've seen all of those above approaches done in the real world in real services.

Comment: this is exactly my concern, however auth0 claims they improve security, which, to me, sounds ridiculous(see conclusion) : https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/  . What has me confused it stormpath also swear by them https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts . Am I crazy or is this a huge risk for the sake of token management

Comment: to boot, auth0 also say you should store these in localStorage which discredits their whole security policy. However, I do respect stormpaths policies, so, that really has me in a twist

Answer (score 1):

Access and Refresh tokens as described in [OpenID on Oauth2](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshTokens) have different purpose:

- **Access token**: grant temporary access to a protected resource, very short lifetime, even single use
- **Refresh token**: Allow to get new tokens, long lived, must be kept secure.

In the OAuth2 authorization flow, after a successful user authentication, the server provides an authorization code that can be used in a second step to get access & refresh token from a token endpoint. The refresh token is stored securely, e.g at server side. The access token is used by client agent to be authenticated.

An access token is only valid until `exp` time. Since they are short-lived,  damage from potential theft is limited. When the access token is close to expire, the refresh token, whose security has not been compromised, is used to get a fresh short-lived access token from token endpoint

Comment: Since the refresh token allows for the production of many tokens, isn't this a big security issue. A group of computers could all login together. Effectively you could grant access to that persons account to anyone

Comment: See point 12.1 of specification (above link). The _token endpoint_ must authenticate the Client before issuing a new token, for example with a secret key of even a digital signature. Even if an attacker stoles a refresh token, he could not use it because does not own the authentication credentials of the token endpoint. Refresh tokens are optional, but for example OpenID Connect implementor like Google use it. Note also that implementation is not trivial, and if the tokens are directly distributed to users (e.g. browsers or devices) without a backend, the refresh token is not too useful

Answer (score 0):

Because, refreshing tokens create new, but also expires the old one with the time, so let suppose someone gets hold of your token but since your server will automatically expire it, the old one would be little or no use of him.

Comment: my whole point is not about the bearer token security, it's about the refresh token security. If I get hold of this as a hacker, game over, I'll spawn tokens at will. I know the answer to this is token blacklisting, but you then have added logic to identify blackened refresh tokens. Sounds like a really risky game to play

Comment: a token may also hold the IP, so if a hacker even gets your token, he has to get same IP as You

Comment: yes, you are talking about csrf defense which can also be hacked. Also, xss attack would circumvent IP defense as the genuine user is requesting the hack from their own account. Let's not assume your token's are unreachable and that hackers can't get users to launch code, the thing is, once you've created a token factory, you've introduced a horrible vulnerability. How are these big services saying this is a good system?

Comment: @user2331566 : how did you solve the security problem for refresh tokens ?

Comment: @jitenshah no, I didn't solve this security problem. However, paypal swears by it's csrf library: https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2016/06/01/securing-your-js-apps-w-stateless-csrf/ . So, altogether jwt(http only)+jwt-csrf appears to be secure, they say they haven't had any issues with that combination

Comment: @user2331566 : Thank you for the link. So, this seems to be a fix for web-based app right ? How does it work for native Android app/iOS app.